# How to print the elements (which are array) of list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have some code in python which outputs the array named datafile. One of the element of that array is: first element for example

```
datafile[0]=(array([[ 1.],
   [ 2.],
   [ 3.],
   [ 4.],
   [ 5.]]), array([[ 10.],
   [ 20.],
   [ 30.],
   [ 40.],
   [ 50.]]))
```

I like to print first and second element of the list:

First element:

```
(array([[ 1.],
   [ 2.],
   [ 3.],
   [ 4.],
   [ 5.]]))
```

What's the easy way to print or separate those elements? Thank you
EDIT:
If I do as you  Joran said then, 
Once I can separate those elements, I want to superimpose plots of datafile[i][0] versus datafile[i][1].

I was trying to achieve that by doing for loop:

```
for i in datafile: 
     plt.plot(datafile[i][0],datafile[i][1]) 
     plt.show
```

But I am getting error "list indices must be integers, not tuple ". I have been stuck on this for a while.

NEVERMIND! I fixed it! Thank you guys for your help! :)

Comment: `print my_array[0]` ?

Comment: I just modified my question. can you understand what I mean? Thanks

Comment: `print datafile[0][0]` and `print datafile[0][1]` ?

Comment: `print [d[0] for d in datafile]` and `print [d[1] for d in datafile]`?

Comment: If you answered your own question, please post your answer as an answer so future readers may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after the edits, I think I found the issue.

in your code:

```
for i in datafile: 
     plt.plot(datafile[i][0],datafile[i][1]) 
     plt.show
```

You are in fact trying to use a tuple ( each datafile[i] element is a tuple) as the index when you call plot.

Try to use something like:

```
for element in datafile: 
     plt.plot(element[0],element[1]) 
     plt.show
```

And next time, try to include as many examples, code, results, etc as you can, as it will help a lot in figuring out the solution ;)

Comment: I think these are numpy arrays... so you have several more slice types to cover :P

Comment: Thank you. ya there are arrays within array within array. :( Can you see my updated question and help me in plotting? Thanks